# How to pass Maven variable to asciidoctor-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have user-guide which uses AsciiDoc it is very beautiful despite that I did not spend much time for it.

AsciiDoc plugins are awesome. So I want to pass my Maven final name in the user guide.

**Question**: How to do that?

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${version.state}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
```

My `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` configurations are:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>${asciidoctorj.pdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Comment this section to use the default jruby artifact provided by the plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
            <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
            <version>${jruby.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Comment this section to use the default AsciidoctorJ artifact provided by the plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
            <version>${asciidoctorj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>src/docs/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
        <sourceDocumentName>manual.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
        <!-- Attributes common to all output formats -->
        <attributes>
            <sourcedir>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcedir>
        </attributes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-pdf-doc</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <backend>pdf</backend>
                <!-- Since 1.5.0-alpha.9 PDF back-end can use 'rouge' as well as 'coderay'
            source highlighting -->
                <sourceHighlighter>rouge</sourceHighlighter>
                <attributes>
                    <icons>font</icons>
                    <pagenums/>
                    <toc/>
                    <idprefix/>
                    <idseparator>-</idseparator>
                </attributes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [official user guide](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin) cover this case in its [Passing POM properties](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin#passing-pom-properties) section:

> It is possible to pass properties defined in the POM to the Asciidoctor processor. This is handy for example to include in the generated document the POM artifact version number.
>
> This is done by creating a custom AsciiDoc property in the `attributes` section of the `configuration`. The AsciiDoc property value is defined in the usual Maven way: `${myMavenProperty}`.
>
> ```
> <attributes>  
>      <project-version>${project.version}</project-version>  
> </attributes>
> ```
>
> The custom AsciiDoc property can then be used in the document like this:
>
> ```
> The latest version of the project is {project-version}.
> ```

Accordingly, you can hence apply the following to your existing `configuration`:

```
<configuration>
    <sourceDirectory>src/docs/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
    <sourceDocumentName>manual.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
    <!-- Attributes common to all output formats -->
    <attributes>
        <sourcedir>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcedir>
        <!-- the new property -->
        <final-name>${project.build.finalName}</final-name>
    </attributes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The User-guide of ASCII Doc is so good to now I feel shamed that I did not find it. Thanks @A. Di Matteo.